# update query with special characters as data in a oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column QUERY1 on the below table,

```
ctrl_id  query1
C001     NULL
```

query to be updated in QUERY1 column - SELECT ‘C001’ as CTRL_ID, ‘SRC1’ as SOURCE, [Company Code], Sum([Total AV]) FROM $Src_tbl1 GROUP BY [Company Code]

Below is the query that i use,

```
update table test1  set QUERY1= ''SELECT ‘C001’ as CTRL_ID, ‘SRC1’ as SOURCE, [Company Code], Sum([Total AV]) FROM $Src_tbl1 GROUP BY [Company Code]'' WHERE CTRL_ID='C001'
```

This query is failing. Please assist.

Comment: You have curly single quotes in the query.  That doesn't look right.

Comment: I couldnt load data after changing the cury quotes to single quotes too.

Comment: Why are you saving query code as data in a table in the first place? That is a sign of some really tortuous thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use 2 single quotes for storing a single quote `'`:

```
update 
  test1  
set QUERY1= 'SELECT ''C001'' as CTRL_ID, ''SRC1'' as SOURCE, [Company Code], Sum([Total AV]) FROM $Src_tbl1 GROUP BY [Company Code] WHERE CTRL_ID=''C001''';
```

This will store the value as:

```
SELECT 'C001' as CTRL_ID, 'SRC1' as SOURCE, [Company Code], Sum([Total AV]) FROM
 $Src_tbl1 GROUP BY [Company Code] WHERE CTRL_ID='C001'
```

As you can see at the end there are 3 single quotes:
the first 2 are used to escape the closing single quote of `'C001'` 
and the 3d to end the whole value of `QUERY1`. 
If you want the value stored as:

```
'SELECT 'C001' as CTRL_ID, 'SRC1' as SOURCE, [Company Code], Sum([Total AV]) FROM $Src_tbl1 GROUP BY [Company Code] WHERE CTRL_ID='C001''
```

then you must do this:

```
update 
  test1  
set QUERY1= '''SELECT ''C001'' as CTRL_ID, ''SRC1'' as SOURCE, [Company Code], Sum([Total AV]) FROM $Src_tbl1 GROUP BY [Company Code] WHERE CTRL_ID=''C001''''';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set query1='select ''coo1'' as ctrl_id, ''src1'' as source,

Company_code,sum (total_avg) from table group by company_code'